# Python, PSSE API, floating point exceptions

Tags: python, psse

**Hello, I have a problem concerning running PSSE from Python. I have a scripts(a tool) written in python 2.7 that call PSSE 34. when I run this tool, I have the following error when I initialize PSSE using this line : psspy.psseinit(12000) .
the error I got :**

```
Invalid Floating-Point number.

Image          PC       Routine Line    Source

libiomp5md.dll 501C64C4 Unknown Unknown Unknown

libiomp5md.dll 5016C874 Unknown Unknown Unknown

libiomp5md.dll 5015E4C9 Unknown Unknown Unknown

psseng.dll 7933C1D3 Unknown Unknown Unknown

psseng.dll 797BDADF Unknown Unknown Unknown

psspyc.pyd 05399520 Unknown Unknown Unknown

python27.dll 5035484B Unknown Unknown Unknown

python27.dll 503A2EA6 Unknown Unknown Unknown 

python.exe 1C621180 Unknown Unknown Unknown 

KERNEL32.DLL 7679FA29 Unknown Unknown Unknown 

ntdll.dll 77AE7A9E Unknown Unknown Unknown 

ntdll.dll 77AE7A6E Unknown Unknown Unknown

Process finished with exit code -1073741680 (0xC0000090)*
```

**However, I tried running a simple test in python : with these two lines :

```
import psspy

psspy.psseinit(12000)
```

I don't get the same error. the execution finised with 'Process finished with exit code 0'

Any suggestion or advise to solve this issue would be very appreciated. Thank you.**

Comment: I'm confused about how you are getting an error, how does that instance differ from your non-error test script?

Comment: Yes, these two lines of the non-error test script, is included in another function, inside a python file, it's a big script that is making error at this point when he is executing <psspy.psseinit(12000)> .  The psspy.psseinit() API initializes an instance of PSSE with the number of buses shown in the parenthesis.  the problem why this API could work alone and, in another script, could not work.  I would like to know what cause an Invalid Floating-Point number. any explantation/idea would be appreciated